# After the package is opened by Customs for inspection, will they provide a letter to clarify that it was opened by them?

Tags: shipping, customs, imports

After the package is opened by Customs for inspection, will they provide a letter or a document to the receiver to clarify that it was opened by them?

Otherwise anyone can rummage through anyone's shyt then blame it on Customs.

Or after Customs did their inspection, anyone can play with your shyt with no repercussion.

From me experiences, customs' reseal methods and what else are not very tamper-proof, some even do udderly feck all to tamper-proofing your shyt after they done.

Comment: Any answer will depend on which customs is being asked about (which hasn't been specified).

Comment: I have found cards or leaflets (not really letters) so yes something like that does occasionally happen.